# Python script to accumulate flow volumes for a pipeline geometric network

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, network-analyst, network

I have a point wells layer and a polyline pipeline layer. The wells are snapped to the end of the pipeline segments. The wells layer has weekly updated flow volumes and I'd like to find a way to automate the transfer of this flow volume from the point layer to a new field in the line segment that the point is attached to.

(I'm aware of spatial joins but this creates a new feature class which won't work because the pipeline layer is part of a geometric network. I just need to transfer the attribute to the original pipeline layer)

Comment: is it one line feature per well? sounds like it but just to clarify. Also, is there a shared attribute between the point feature(s) and the line feature?

Comment: No only some pipeline segments have wells connected to them, and there is also no common attribute.. I think Hornbydd's method below might just work. Thanks for the response though!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this is the following way:

1. Run a spatial join to create a temporary dataset, you need to do this as this gives the ID relation you want, well ID *X* is on polyline ID *Y*.
2. Create a standalone table from this spatial join which has nothing more than your polyline ID, Well ID and Flow volume.
3. Join this table to your geometric network layer
4. Run a calculate on the field in the geometric layer that will hold the flow value and pass in the flow value from the joined flow. This will obviously overwrite any existing value.
5. Remove join

That is it! You could easily automate all this with model builder so all you need to supply is the geometric network and well layer. If you do not know what model builder is then I'm afraid it is time for you to read the help file.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you very much. I've worked with model builder but I'm hoping to create a python script tool. This problem is just the beginning of what I'm trying to do.  
Once the pipeline segments have inherited the flow volumes from the wells layer, I'd like to find a way to automatic the flow accumulation down the entire pipeline so that once the script is run, a user could query a pipeline segment and see the flow volume at that segment.

This will involve some tricky coding, and I'm not sure it's possible for python to recognize the flow direction of each segment...

Comment: arcpy to my knowledge does not expose geometric network properties so you'll need to write this using ArcObjects. I've personally never worked with pipeline scenarios so the following question make not be appropriate but how do you intend to deal with bifurcations (loops) in the network when you are accumulating your flow volumes? In rivers you can get loops within loops, these are what are often called braided sections. Just curious?

Comment: My pipeline feature class is radial in nature so I won't have to deal with loops (thank god). If the solution to this involves ArcObjects, I am hooped because I don't know the first thing about it. My one hope is using Arc Hydro's "Find Next Downstream Segment" tool, which somehow assigns ID's to downstream connected segments using the digitized direction of the features. I'm still playing around with this but I was hoping that python could then tap into those downstream IDs somehow in accumulating the flow volume. I'll let you know if it works! Thanks for the help